# Random effects structure for product assessment

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

Could I have some advice which, if any, random-effects structure should be added to my model please.

My data includes multiple people (50) indicating whether they like/don't like a bunch of toys (15). Not every person gives a measure for each toy. The predictors are descriptions of each toy; colouful, fluffy, battery-operated, and such.

The aim is to get a prediction of whether a new toy will be liked given its feature set by a new individual. The data looks like:

```
Person Toy Like X1 X2 X3
     1   1    0  1  1  0
     1   2    0  0  1  0
     1   3    1  0  0  0
     1   4    1  0  1  0
     2   2    0  1  1  1
     2   3    1  0  0  0
     2   4    1  1  1  0
     2   5    1  0  0  1
```

I am using a logistic regression model. I have estimated a random-intercept model using 'Person' as the grouping variable.

```
Like = X1 + X2 + X3 + (1|Person)
```

Is this sensible. Should I, and if so how should I, include the 'Toy' indicator? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a case of partially crossed random effects.

There are repeated measures for `Person` and also for `Toy`. So, observations made by the same `Person` on different `Toy`s are likely to be more similar to each other than for a different `Person` on different `Toy`s. The same applies to `Toy` - observations made on the same `Toy` are likely to be more similar to each other than for a different `Toy`.  So you would specify a model with random intercepts for both `Person` and `Toy`. There is apparently no nesting of random effects (that is, no particular toy "belongs" to a particular person or vice versa), so using the syntax in the OP, to specify crossed random effects for your data you can use:

```
Like ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (1|Person) + (1|Toy)
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you Robert. I appreciate the help.